# same GooglePlus client object in different activities android

Tags: android, singleton, google-plus

I want to create a library for GooglePlus. For this I created multiple classes like login, posting, fetching user profile.

Do I have to implement onConnected, onDisconnected, onConnectionFailed ?
Do I have to call plusClient.connect() in every class?

Currently If I connect() in first(login) class and then tries to post on use's account from different activity then it's giving a problem. I have to connect() it again even if i have done this in previous activity.

Is there a solution for this that I can use same plusClient object in multiple activities?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PlusClient` class is designed to be lightweight so that there is no need to share a `PlusClient` instances across activity instances.  See:

[Access google plus client from multiple activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827839/access-google-plus-client-from-multiple-activities/16832398#16832398)

That said, there is nothing which prevents you from doing this as long as you make sure that `PlusClient.connect()` and `PlusClient.disconnect()` are called at appropriate times if you manage your `PlusClient` as part of a service or application object.

Also, note that `PlusClient` has now been deprecated in favour of `GoogleApiClient`.  For this discussion though, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation that `GoogleApiClient` will help you with.  Make the caller responsible for managing the lifecycle of `GoogleApiClient`.  Have them pass it in to your library.  There you can add a `ConnectionCallbacks` listener and perform your action in `onConnected`.

This also means that your library isn't responsible for handling connection failures.  It's the caller's job in this case.  Generally this isn't something you want in your library anyway, unless you're providing base Activity/Fragment classes.  If that's the case then go ahead and handle those cases here.  This way it's not sprinkled throughout your code.