# Check if a device google account is authenticated, only then allow access to my offline app

Tags: android, authentication, android-account

I have a private app which works totally offline (i.e. no server data sent/recieved), however I have a need to restrict it only to users with a valid Google account on their phone.  I can get make sure there is a suitable account on the phone by iterating a list of phone accounts, but is it possible to check the account is valid/authenticated without me having to introduce the full OAuth process?  I have no need to get a cookie or send any data to a server.

Ideally I'd like to do something like: 
1. Check with the account manager for an auth token.
2. If token recieved then allow access to the app.
Currently without any checks via the account manager, anyone could create a fake account on the phone and then gain access even if they put in a email/password and they would never be authorised.

I hope I've explained this clearly.  As my app has no network connectivity so I would like to avoid adding any of my own network/oauth checking.

Comment: What is a 'fake account' in your opinion? In order to register a Google account, you need a valid username/password combination, those are checked online. Also, getting a token may require online access if one is not cached, so this is not going to work 'totally offline'

Comment: @NikolayElenkov I would say a fake account is one that was setup and didnt not authenticate - I was able to do it easily and in effect bypass a simple account presense based verification.

Comment: You cannot add a Google account if you don't authenticate at leas once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this:

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
final boolean connected = accounts != null && accounts.length > 0;
```

The connected boolean will indicate if there is a connected Google account in the phone.

Indeed there won't be any check on the token, but if the account is registered on the phone, then Google checked it before, server-side, to validate it...

Comment: But, password may have been changed, account may have been hacked, etc., so the listed accounts are not necessarily valid.

Comment: I will need to test this out but I'd assume if the password was changed or account disabled then something else on the device would invalidate the token to cause the connected boolean to become false?  Will post back results in a couple of days.

Comment: There is no immediate feedback, you have to try to use a token to find out that it is invalidated. BTW the `connected` variable is misnamed, it simply shows that at least one account exists.

Comment: I accepted this as my answer since it does what I needed without the burden of google API console, whilst the solution isn't perfect it is sufficient for my needs.  Anyone using it should understand it's weaknesses and know the solution by @acapulco is more reliable.

Comment: These are the account that are added to the phone. They may have been changed (password) and not logged in. So this is not very useful in my case.

Answer (score 2):

How about implementing Google Plus login API? It's not really setting up a full OAuth process since G+ it's fairly simpler, even if it is actually built on top of OAuth.

I use that in an app I'm developing that also does not require online access (except for initial G+ login access).

What I do is the first time the app is run I present the G+ login button. After user clicks on it he can accept the permissions request from my app (to be able to retrieve user email and some basic profile info, i.e. minimum permission needed) and if the API client connects correctly then I present the user with the dashboard or home screen and also set up a flag in SharedPreferences about the user being already authorized.

In this way, the next time the user starts the app it will remember it was already authorized and just ask the API client to connect (only if the access was revoked from the account's Play Store website do we need to re-verify that the user auth is still valid), and everything should work. If the user revokes the access to his G+ profile from my app, I clear the flag so the next time the user runs it it asks for authorization again.

It's actually very simple and at least for my use case (Which sounds very similar to yours) it works for what I want it with minimum user intrusion.

I strongly suggest you try out something like this [Google Plus login tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)

Edit: You can also check this question I asked before, about [working with multiple activities that need Google Plus functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368520/how-to-correctly-use-google-plus-sign-in-with-multiple-activities)

Also, forgot to say that with this method you are always sure that the user account is always valid since you are checking directly with Google's servers about its validity.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but where your users/google accounts also G+ users? Did they need to sign-up to G+ first to use this method?

Comment: Having looked through the Google Plus login turotial it seems this process is almost the same as the regular Google oAuth process as both require use of the api console and play services lib.  I was hoping to do this without any api console use so it's not quite what I'm looking for but realise it may be unavoidable without the risk of stale tokens.

Comment: It is a very similar process to the OAuth implementation but I did find it quite easy to implement. However in the end it will be a trade off between how simple do you want to keep the login process and how secure and accurate it will be. If you do care about a user trying to game the system, your best bet is using the provided APIs. It won't get any simpler (and correct) than that I think. If you opt for designing your own solution chances are that there will be ways around it and fixing errors might make it in the end not worth it.

Comment: @sham I do expect my users to have Google accounts already. As far as I know you can use G+ login with any valid Google account. No need to signup for G+ I think.